# React/CSS problem with background-image and navbar

Tags: css, reactjs

I've got a problem. I'm currently building a frontend with React and the whole html element has a background-image set to linear-gradient in CSS. I have a NavBar with position: fixed and my problem is, when I scroll down the rest of my page content the NavBar's background gets overlaid with the scrolled page content. I can't set the background-image for NavBar separately since it would break the appearance of the linear-gradient. Any suggestions how to get rid of the content overlaying NavBar's background?

Setting main page's content to overflow: hidden doesn't help. As well as inheriting the background-image. I don't know what else to try...

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please could you post a [example] so we can debug your code as best as we can?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `z-index` to your NavBar element?

Comment: yup, I tried, but it only prevented the content (not background) of Nav from being overlayed. Anyways, I was given an answer so problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent the content from scrolling passed the navigation bar is to limit the height of the content container to the viewport.

- `html` & `body` has `height: 100%`
- `body` has `overflow-y: hidden`
- `main` has `overflow-y: auto`
- the height of `main` is calculated as 100% minus the height of `nav`

It'll be easier to use a [custom property (variable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) `--nav-height` to define the height of `nav` instead of having to update this value in multiple places.

In this example, `section` has `height: 1000px` to force overflow instead of using more filler content.

```css
html {
  --nav-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--nav-height);
}

main {
  position: relative;
  top: var(--nav-height);
  height: calc(100% - var(--nav-height));
  overflow-y: auto;
}

section {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<nav>nav content</nav>

<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! you cannot imagine how much I struggled with it. You made my day :)